# What is causing an increase in file size to my "/dev/sda1" directory and how can I reduce the overall size?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, storage

I recently had to increase the file size of "/dev/sda1" from 10GB to 50GB, but I am curious as to why the file size was so large to begin with. I am hosting a WordPress site through Google Cloud Platform and the WordPress site itself is 762MB. What else could be adding to the file size (9GB worth)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so it looks like the cache folder was increasing in size from all of the automatic installs.

Check this folder size: `du -ch /var/cache/apt/archives/`

This article helped explain what was going on and how to clear it up:
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/can-i-delete-var-cache-apt-archives-for-ubuntu-debian-linux/

I ended up using: `sudo apt autoclean`

This reduced 6GB of storage. Now the real question is did I mess something up when I increased the disk size from 10GB to 50GB? I read somewhere that the disk is created to encrypt a certain portion of the disk, but increasing it's size, I am not sure if that affects the overall encryption of the disk.

Comment: `/dev/sda` is a device node representing the persistent disk. `/dev/sda1` is partition #1 on that device. Google Cloud Persistent disk performance is directly related to size. There is nothing wrong with increasing the disk size. Larger disks do cost more but have higher performance. The entire disk device remains encrypted.

Comment: Thank you @JohnHanley for taking time to reply to my question/answer! Looks like I am good to go then.

Comment: Double check that the file system resized after you increased the disk size. This is usually automatic. Use a command such as `df -h` to list the mounted file systems. Most likely you will see the new space mounted on `/`.